# Offer vs Potential Offer

Tags: job-offer

So I was verbally offered a job some 7 weeks ago (early Dec 2019) and we've agreed on payment etc, but no physical contract came in so I could not sign anything, I reached out to the recruiter and the hiring manager and was given the excuse/reason that there was rebudgeting and sales kick off - some 5 weeks ago - I reached out to the hiring manager to check on the status, she then told me that they were only given 1 headcount and that went to Japan which meant, my role was then put on hold indefinitely.

Last week, the recruiter came back to me and told me that the senior leadership has approved my headcount and is ready to churn out the contract for me. This whole process has been a tedious wait of 7 weeks. And they want me to start in slightly less than 2 weeks.

Meanwhile, because it was so ambiguous -- I started going for interviews again. And went for an interview where it was really good - I got along so well with the hiring manager and they accelerated my interview process and I've completed the final rounds in less than 2 weeks. I don't know if I will be offered, but I am really keen on this new opportunity.

Should I be transparent with the new opportunity and let them know that I've been offered? So that I can press for an answer quickly?

Next, should I still consider the company that made me wait for 7 weeks? I also know that they laid off some people in the US HQ in December 2019. Which is kinda red flag plus the long wait.

Please help!

Comment: My answer is simple, thus a comment. I would want a signed written offer. So, yes, tell both companies that, then take the offer whichever comes first

Comment: You should absolutely tell the new company that you have an offer in hand, and they want an answer in the next week, so that the new company can accelerate their interview process.

Comment: By taking so long to get their act together, the first company took upon themselves the risk of losing you. They didn't expect you to stop interviewing. They certainly had no reason or right to expect it. Who knows, if you take the second job maybe you can recruit the hiring manager from your first job; she or he cannot be pleased about this 7-week bumbling.

Answer (score 4):

Your desired outcome is to compare both offers and take the one you like best.  So yes, I would mention to the second company “I have an offer in hand from another company.  I’ve really liked our discussions, however, and was wondering when I might hear about an offer from you.” They will then accelerate as possible/desired on their end. I would then also put off the first company a bit, saying “I will need a little more time to decide and won’t be able to join on that aggressive of a timeframe.” Ideally you get the second offer before the first one gets impatient, and you can make a decision.

Of course it depends on your situation.  If you’re unemployed and desperately need a job, then it’s not a good idea to do this because you could be left with no offers.  But for a normal job change without undue pressure, some brinksmanship is fine.

Is the slowness a “red flag?”  In general I’m not a fan of everyone deciding anything a company does inefficiently is some kind of deal-killer; that’s just Internet Tough Guy talk.  But it is a factor to take into account as the overall package of which position to take.

I had a very similar thing happen to me - I’d been talking to one company about a leadership position and they started going through the same gyrations, but for months.  “Well the hiring manager left...”  “Well were having trouble with a perm role, how about contract to hire?  No?” (I was in a perm job with benefits, and their role was not so stunning that I wanted to do my own benefits and have greater risk of he job being short term, etc.) It took more than 3 months for them to finally sack up and put together an offer.  But of course just as they did, I got an offer from a smaller company where I knew someone I’d be working with. I took the second position based on a mix of factors - the work, the people, the pay, and, yes, because they had revealed to me through the process that probably as a leader in org #1 it would take me an untoward amount of time and effort to hire (and possibly to do other things) as well.  Company #1 was upset because of the “time and effort” they’d put in over months of trying to get things to work, but of course so had I.

But having said that, I wouldn’t have accepted a radically worse offer from company #2 just because company #1 had sand in their drawers; if they were offering lots more money or higher position or more interesting work or something I’d “get over it.”  They weren’t, and one of my goals was to build my own team so their hiring travails were more than just an arbitrary “bad thing” to me but would directly affect my ability to do what I needed.  But I wanted to change jobs because the company I was with sucked (had been bought out by vulture capitalists), so I would have taken offer 1 if it was the only one.

That’s a long anecdotey way of saying don’t be suckered in by people trying to get you to make overly simplistic career choices based on one specific detail. Work to optimize your own career; make smart decisions and tradeoffs about when and how hard to push for multiple offers, factor in all the attributes of offers when deciding on them, and so on.

Answer (score -3):

Since the first company made you wait seven weeks to find out if they even have a job they could offer you, they have no right to insist that you decide in less than two weeks -- a completely different time scale. They are not worth rushing for.

Now you are probably going to get an offer from the second company, and you would prefer to join them.

So imagine that the first company is out of the picture. How long are you willing to wait for an offer from the second company before you give up and start interviewing again?

Tell the first company that you want that much time to decide on their offer.

Since the second company has already accelerated your interview process, it seems unnecessary and most probably useless to press them for an answer quickly.